# Documentation about functions used in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, function, reporting-services

I will keep it as short as possible. ( Please take into consideration , that I am not familiar with c# programming / dll and such things. I have been mostly working in the Data Analysis world with python )

I have a report in SSRS in Visual Studio that I would like to add some embedded code.

[image: Report Properties>>Code]

And i am trying to call those functions that are available for the SSRS
[image: Expression Window]

Microsoft Documentation states that for those functions you could call them by given the specific class.

for example
Math.Floor()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/custom-code-and-assembly-references-in-expressions-in-report-designer-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

*. For convenience, you can view the most commonly used functions in the Expression dialog box, where they are listed by category: Text, Date and Time, Math, Inspection, Program Flow, Aggregate, Financial, Conversion, and Miscellaneous. Less commonly used functions do not appear in the list but can still be used in an expression.*

I am trying to use the lookup function in the code
[image]

by calling Miscellaneous.Lookup

[image]

but somehow I get an error that this class does not exist.
do you have any idea where is the API/DEV Documentation related to this. I cannot really find any documentation reference to that function.

[image]

If I try with Math.Floor(1) it actually works

[image]

another a little bit more complex code

[image]
[image]

```
public function a(byVal x as Integer) as String
 if(x = 1 ) then
 Return Math.Floor(1)
else Return 2
end if
end function
```

**EDIT:** ( Thanks @Timothy G. )

Miscellaneous.Lookup(1,1,"holaInLookup","DataSet1")

Still same error
[image]

Comment: There are 4 parameters to the `Miscellaneous.Lookup` function, you appear to only be passing in 3.  Could that be the issue?  There is a small example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-introducing-expressions?view=sql-server-ver15#Lookup) you may want to look at.

Comment: @TimothyG., 

thanks for the tip. Unfortunately that does not change, due to it is telling me that it cannot find the Miscellaneous.Lookup class

Miscellaneous.Lookup(1,1,"holaInLookup","DataSet1")

Comment: I think you might be almost there.  Maybe this will be of some use to you in how to reference other assemblies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-an-assembly-reference-to-a-report-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: These functions, since they are already defined, can be applied directly to the fields on the report. Assuming you put a Table on the report, and dragged-and-dropped fields from your Data Source to the report, you can right-click the desired data field, select Expression, and use the built-in functions there. By putting them at the Report level, you're just wrapping the built-in functions with additional code. What does your report definition look like?

Comment: Also, in your screen shot of Lookup, notice the example usage:  `=Lookup(....` Miscellaneous isn't a "namespace" and is not part of the function call. This example uses `=LookUp...` as the function call, and the `=` sign indicates it's being applied to a data field Expression as described in my previous comment.

Comment: I think you might be misinterpreting the documentation. You can use functions in the `expression builder` such as `=IIF(Fields!myField.Value.Contains("abc"), "y", "n")` as well as standard expression functions such as `LOOKUP()` with `=LOOKUP(Fields!EmpID.Value, Fields!EmployeeID.Value, Fields!Name.Value, "dsEmployees")`. You can also use functions from the convert and math libraries in the custom code window because references are automatically added. For any other libraries, you need to add an explicit reference to the report in the report properties window/references tab

Comment: Why can't you just use the Lookup in your Text box? `=IIF(Fields.X.Value = 1, LOOKUP(1, 1, "holaInLookup", "DataSet1"), 2)`? There doesn't seem to be an equivalent for VB.

Comment: @HardCode, I know i can apply these directly to the fields ( <expr> ). but what I want to avoid is having to write and maintain around 60 exprs. so basically reducing the complexity from lookup(id,id, "hola","Dataset1") to  a(id). that is why of the need of the custom code.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, 
_"For any other libraries, you need to add an explicit reference to the report in the report properties window/references tab"_
exactly Math and Convert are already there. there are also some other functions from VB
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/runtime-library-members). 

My problem: I cannot find the reference documentation where Lookup is included. ( I do not know from which class/assembly/dll this lookup is coming ). is there any way to figure that out?

Comment: @HannoverFist, as I mentioned to Hardcode . I want to reduce the complexity. because it wil lbe around 60 expresssions, with some conditional statements and const strings.

Comment: @OscarCopado if you have to apply expressions to 60 fields, would it maybe be easier to get closer to your final results in the actual query instead? Is the source of the Lookup in the same database that your query data is in?

Comment: @HardCode, 

I thought of the same. ( just coding that directly in the SQL, but because of the headers I see no other solution than:
The solution changes the headers depending on the language selected ( if EN then EnglishHeaders, OtherLanguageHeaders )

Comment: So I am running in to a similar issue. We created a lookup dataset (lets call it mappingData) and then on the report, I can go in and modify expression to say =LOOKUP(<my value>, Fields!Key.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "mappingData") But I wanted to do some additional logic so wanted to move it to a function. When I try to do that, I get a BC30451 Lookup is not a function error... how do I access/call the Lookup function from Report's code section?